# Convert a raw chainspec to the original format

Tags: chainspec

Is there a way to revert a raw chainspec to the original format?

Comment: Where did you get the chain spec? Which commands are you using? What are you trying to do with the spec?

Comment: Just as an addition, build-spec subcommand do not allow raw to plain conversion. So not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no automatic way for this. It would not be impossible as long as you have the native runtime that you used to build the raw chain spec. However, no one before required this before and thus, it is not supported.